# Array with literal strings

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, heap-memory

I am having a `string` array initialized with literal strings as below:

```
public static void Main()
{
     string[] values = new string[] { "Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Rat" };
}
```

So we have following structure on Stack and Heap:

**OnStack:** A variable `values` holding reference to the array of string on heap.

**OnHeap:** The array of string which is referenced by `values` on stack

---

But what will be the content of each element of the array on heap ?

> 1. Actual string literals ?
> 2. References pointing to string literals in intern pool ?

---

**Edit:** The question was pointed as duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087987/how-is-an-array-of-value-types-stored-in-net-object-heap). But my case is different in terms that

1. Another question was in context to how value type as elements of array behave, that showed that question poser was not clear how ref/val type objects are allocated on stack/heap.
2. In my question I am clear how ref/val type elements are allocated on stack or heap but I am discussing the special case when the objects are string literals. Because that has to deal with intern pool and GC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is an array of value types stored in .NET object heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087987/how-is-an-array-of-value-types-stored-in-net-object-heap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, considering Microsoft .NET CLR (this is important only for the position of the `values`, if in stack or heap), you'll have 5 references to 5 objects.

To be precise, you have an array of `string`s (1 object), that is an array of references to `string` (another 4 objects).

The five references are:

- `values` (in this case on the stack)
- 4x references to 4x interned `string`s (contained on the heap, in the `string[]` array)

The five objects are:

- an array of `string[]`, contained in the heap
- 4x `string` objects that are interned, but they still are fully fledged `object`s, the only difference is that the GC won't ever free them (unless their `AppDomain` is unloaded)

So it is

> References pointing to string literals in intern pool ?

Comment: As a corollary (to conform): If I had 4 non-literal string variables initializing the string array, the actual strings would be elements of the array ?

Comment: @NirajDoshi No, a `string[]` array is an array of references to `string`, **always**. There is no practical difference between an interned `string` and a non-interned `string`, other than its lifetime and that some static `string` methods (`Intern` and `IsInterned`) can be used to retrieve an interned `string`/check if a `string` is interned.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite the same as if you create:

```
class MyArray
{
     string first;
     string second; 
     string third;
     ... more strings
}
```

And create instance of it:

```
class MyArray instance = new MyArray();
```

This will result in memory allocation for MyArray instance, and number of related fields on heap. It also creates reference that points to this object and references to all related fields. Same with array except that you use references to a fields by accessing array indexer rather then make direct calls like `instance.first`

Comment: Good example which gives more clearer understanding of how arrays actually behave. But my question one more step ahead as in terms of string literals. Because string literals behave specially in .net CLR

Comment: @NirajDoshi: For your one step ahead thing, you have to know about how string intern pool behaves. If it finds any value in table, it will just return the reference address of that value rather than creating a new entry with same value. This is 2nd one you are asking for.